# SELECT statement with sub-query

Tags: sql-server

Instructions:

Business case: The accounting department would like a reporting of the top ten vendors with their last invoice date and average invoice amount.

Write a SELECT statement that returns three columns:

- VendorName (from the Vendors table)
- LatestInv (summary function that returns the last entry from InvoiceDate)
- AverageInv: (summary function that returns the average from InvoiceTotal)

Hint: you will need to join two tables before joining to the derived table (the subquery)

Subquery portion: SELECT statement that returns the top ten VendorID and AverageInv (same name and function as described in the outer query). Group the results by the appropriate column and sort the results by AverageInv from largest to smallest. Correlate the subquery as BestVendors and join it to the correct table (where both share a key field).

Group the outer query by the appropriate column and sort the results by LatestInv 
most recent to oldest

My code

```
SELECT VendorName, MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LatestInv, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
FROM Vendors v JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 10 VendorID, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
    FROM Invoices
    GROUP BY VendorID
    ORDER BY AverageInv DESC) AS BestVendors
    ON v.VendorID = BestVendors.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorName
ORDER BY LatestInv
```

`MAX(InvoiceDate)` has a red line under it as well as `AVG(InvoiceTotal)` because they are from the Invoices table. Not the Vendors. However if I use `FROM Invoices` in the outer query then `VendorName` won't be recognized? How do I fix this and get the result set that this question is looking for?

Also these pics show some sample data from the Invoices and Vendors Table

[image: Vendors]

[image: Invoices]

Comment: Your BestVendor select doesn't return InvoiceDate so the column doesn't exist.  Shouldn't your subquery be `SELECT TOP 10 VendorID, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv, MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LatestInv` and then you main query would be `SELECT VendorName, LatestInv, AverageInv`

Comment: Your inner query (`BestVendors`) is correct, except that it required the `MAX(InvoiceDate)`. For the outer query, you don't need the `GROUP BY` as you have already perform it in the inner query

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The Instrucions require me to write it how I wrote it, unless I'm missing something. It says to list those 3 columns in the outer query and only two in the subquery??

Comment: @Squirrel I only have that GROUP BY There because its stated to have it there from the instructions

Comment: You have already perform a `GROUP BY` in the inner query. So there will not be any duplicate `VendorID`. So when you `JOIN` with `Vendors` table you should not get any duplicate `VendorID` in the result. (Unless you have duplicate VendorID value in the Vendor table)

Comment: Or Maybe your right @JerryJeremiah Maybe I'm not suppose to follow the instructions top to bottom maybe they won't me to write it that way. You think? Is there really any other way?

Comment: Ok I removed that but it doesn' fix the issue of the LatestInv and AvgInvoice columns not being recognized

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT VendorName, BestVendors.LatestInv, BestVendors.AverageInv
FROM Vendors v 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 10 VendorID
              ,AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
              ,MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LatestInv
    FROM Invoices
    GROUP BY VendorID
    ORDER BY AverageInv DESC
) AS BestVendors
    ON v.VendorID = BestVendors.VendorID
ORDER BY LatestInv DESC
```

Comment: `sort the results by LatestInv most recent to oldest`. OP missed the `DESC`